# Trying to trigger jQuery Mobile ajax call

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm sure this is a basic syntax error but I'm trying to make a rest call using jQuery mobile ajax (code below) and as far as I can tell the ajax is not triggering.

```
        function triggerCall() {
            alert("function triggered");
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: REST Url,
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Any errors or console messages?

Answer (score 0):

if you're actually writing `url: REST Url,` then you must change it to either a var, or a string.. that would be a problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you're using JSONP, you need to specify the callback in the $.ajax request and then again in your REST file return. Here is an example of what I've been using succesfuly (It's not perfect though, I'm sure).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'www.domain.com/string/to/your/REST/api',
    data: {
        dataToBeSent: variable, 
        dataToBeSent: sessionStorage.getItem('local/session Storage'),
        dataToBeSend: "or a string"
    },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
    timeout: 5000,
    success: function(data){    
        alert("Huzzah!");
    },
    error: function(){
        alert("Boohisssss");
    }
}); //end ajax call
```

And then in the url, I'd place this code at the bottom of the file:

```
header("Content-type: application/json", true);
echo $_GET['jsoncallback'] . '(' . json_encode($data) . ');';
exit;
```

Where data is a array that is JSON encoded, using json_encode() in PHP, and then wrapped up in a callback function (the $_GET['jsoncallback'])

Like I said, it's not perfect, but it's been working for me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for errors in browser console. eg. in chrome menu>tools>javascript console.
2. Also recommend adding an error handler to your ajax call:  http://api.jquery.com/error/
3. Determine which method, JSONP or CORS, to use for your restful ajax calls: [So, JSONP or CORS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296910/so-jsonp-or-cors) .