# Unable to post data using JSONP on Cross Domain

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

We have a scenario where we need to post data from our domain (x.com) to a different domain (y.com). The action on the y.com is attributed `HTTPPost` and it can be changed. But while posting data to the y.com using `AJAX` and `JSONP` with `HTTPMethod POST` the request is automatically converted to `HTTPMethod GET`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't POST using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about/6879319#6879319) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11736431/make-cross-domain-ajax-jsonp-request-with-jquery/11736771#11736771)) because it just [doesn't work that way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508198/how-to-use-type-post-in-jsonp-ajax-call/4508215#4508215) - it creates a `<script>` element to fetch data, which has to be done via GET request. JSONP solution doesn't use `XmlHttpRequest` object, so it is not an AJAX request in the standard way of understanding, but the content is still accessed dynamically - no difference for the end user.

JSONP can be indeed used to overcome [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restriction, but alternatively you can  use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), implemented in modern browsers [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296910/so-jsonp-or-cors/12309651#12309651) to JSON with Padding.

Answer (score 0):

`JSONP` request are `GET` request and cannot be made with `POST` requests. If you want to sent a post request look into Cross origin Resource Sharing.

Answer (score 0):

As a work around what you can do is to resolve CrossDomain communication using postMessage which is a new feature of HTML5. However, in order for your to resolve it you will need to use iframes and in the case if you do not want to display some iframe, you can create it 1x1px with display:none css property.
This will allow you to achieve your goal.