# Returning variable value from controller to view

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm new at Laravel and I'm actively trying to code better, but I'm currently stuck with problems I don't know how to solve.

The controller :

```
public function sendGiving($contents){
    $redirectURL = $contents->redirectURL;
    var_dump($redirectURL); // the variable is available, logged in network section
    return View::make('giving/giving')->with('redirectURL', $redirectURL);
}
```

The view (on AJAX) :

```
function submitForm() {
    if (is_personal_data_complete() == true && is_offering_filled() == true && isreCaptchaChecked() == true) {
        var base_url = window.location.origin;
        
        //send ajax request    
        $.post("{{ route('send_giving') }}",
            {
                _method: 'POST',
                _token: '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                name: $('#txtName').val(),
                email: $('#txtEmail').val(),
                phone_number: $('#txtnohp').val(),
                thanksgiving_offerings: total_thanksgiving,
                tithe_offerings: total_tithe,
                firstborn_offerings: total_firstborn,
                build_offerings: total_build,
                deacon_offerings: total_deacon,
                mission_offerings: total_mission,
                paud_offerings: total_paud,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                async : false,
                success: function($redirectURL){
                    alert($redirectURL);
                },
            });
            
    }
       
    else if (is_personal_data_complete() == false) {
        alert("Please fill in your data form");
    }
    else if (is_offering_filled() == false) {
        alert("Please fill in your offerings");
    }
    else if (isreCaptchaChecked() == false){
        alert("Please check the captcha");
    }
    return false;
}
```

The alert always returns `undefined` though, what am I missing?

Comment: I think, `redirectURL` is not on ajax call, because you send this on view `View::make('giving/giving')`. If this is, then you need to catch `{{ $redirectURL }}`

Comment: sorry if this sounds dumb, but, how do i catch var from the view back to ajax ?

Comment: Post your full ajax code

Comment: ive edit it on question, its too long for comment

Comment: Remove the var_dump in your controller

Comment: Seems like you need to pass an second parameter on ajax call,  which is `$contents`,  then you need a json response, like  `return response()->json([
    'redirectURL' => $redirectURL
]);`

Answer (score 0):

The **view()** function just creates an instance of the View class. Not just an HTML string. For that you should call **render()**:

```
$returnHTML = view('giving/giving')->with('redirectURL', $redirectURL)->render();
return response()->json(array('success' => true, 'html'=>$returnHTML));
```

Comment: can you explain further? its still undefined but i want to know the logic

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:
`return response()->json($redirectURL)`

When you use Laravel and write API, you need to use this command to reponse JSON for frontend

Comment: still returning undefined

Answer (score 0):

When you return in your controller `return View::make('giving/giving')->with('redirectURL', $redirectURL);`

You are returning a VIEW file, which will be return as the `body` of the HTTP request.

and you are also passing to Your view file `redirectUrl` which will be accessible in your view file.

And when you perform your **AJAX** request, you are getting a response with a body which contain `HTML/TEXT` Content not *JSON*.

**SO YOU CAN'T HAVE ACCESS TO `redirectURL` VARIABLE**

So what you should do by the way is to return simple a **JSON** body by returning in your Controller something like

```
return response()->json([
    'redirectURL' => $redirectURL
]);
```

No need to return a `VIEW FILE`

**You can't return in the same controller `JSON data` in the body and a `VIEW FILE`**

Comment: if im understanding right, this is just returning json var 'redirectURL' from body, but then how to access it on my ajax call ? Because it still undefined

Comment: you're right, in your the `success` settings of the `ajax` function you can have access to the `JSON` return from your controller as parameter. You should just ensure that your ajax request are handled by the right controller and return the right `JSON` data.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is here that you try to send a POST with JSONP data type.
There are a lot of explanations on this on SO, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934048/8574551

Try to remove it and use smth like the next:

```
...
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
...
```

On another hand, you can omit these 2 parameters (check https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

To return the data from the controller action you can use `response()->json(..)` (as described in other answers)

Answer (score 0):

the problem is on the ajax request, as after changing the format it works nicely