# Why is jQuery post() sending a GET request?

Tags: jquery, rest

I have a simple, stupid, single-file "application" that is intended to demonstrate how to interact with an API server for digest authentication.  The first step is to `POST` with no credentials and get back a `nonce`.  But when I call `$.post(...)`, the network trace shows a `GET` and the console records "method not allowed".

The console shows a 405 but by the time my code sees it, `request.status` is 404.  I don't care because what should happen is I `POST` and get back a 401.

I found many questions about jQuery sending `POST` instead of `GET` but most are quite old and the solutions either don't help me or don't apply to my situation.

I verified that I'm using jQuery 3.5.1 so older answers about `type` vs. `method` don't seem to apply.

I get the same behavior in Chrome and Edge.

If you save the following as `index.html` and open it in Chrome, clicking the button sends a `GET` request.  To `google.com` that likely succeeds but why `GET`?!  If I put in my REST API server's URL, the code sends `GET` and I get back a 405 because `GET` isn't supported on that end point.

I feel like I must be missing something obvious but I don't know what.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>SSO Test Client</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/site.css" />
    <script src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/site.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
    <style>
      input[type="text"] {
          width: 50em;
      }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        async function init() {
            console.log(jQuery(). jquery);

            // Doesn't matter what I put here, it fails
            $("#server").val("https://google.com");

            $("#submit").click(handleSubmit);
        };

        function handleSubmit() {
            var server = $("#server").val();
            // Get nonce from API server by attempting to post without credentials
            // and handling the challenge response.
            $.post({
                url: server,
                dataType: "jsonp",  // I get back a 0 response without this
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type':'application/json'  //  The server seems to require this
                },
                data: {},
                success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                    // This should never succeed; we expect a 401
                    alert(textStatus);
                },
                // Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14563181/7685
                error: function (request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var msg = "";

                    if (request.status == 0) {
                        msg = `Could not connect to "${server}".`;
                    }
                    else if (request.status == 404) {
                        msg = "Page not found (404)";
                    }
                    else if (request.status == 405) {
                        msg = "Method not allowed (405)";
                    }
                    else if (request.status == 500) {
                        msg = "Internal server error (500)";
                    }
                    // This is expected.
                    else if (request.status == 401) {
                        msg = "Got nonce from server.";
                    }
                    else {
                        msg = "Unhandled status. " + textStatus;
                    }

                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        };

        function docReady(fn) {
            // see if DOM is already available
            if (document.readyState === "complete" || document.readyState === "interactive") {
                // call on next available tick
                setTimeout(fn, 1);
            } else {
                document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
            }
        };

        docReady(init);
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <main role="main" class="pb-3">
            <div class="text-center">
                <div id="sso-client">
                    <input id="server" type="text"
                           title="API server to use for SSO authorization" />
                    <br />
                    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Test"
                           title="Try to get a nonce" onclick=""/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

A few notes:

1. I'm willing to believe that the `jsonp` data type is what's making jQuery convert `POST` to `GET` but without that, I get a status code of 0 and nothing goes out on the network.

   - If I remove the `jsonp`, then I need to know how to get the request to go out at all.
2. I tried adding `jQuery.support.cors = true;` before `$.post()` and it didn't make any difference
3. I don't believe I need to make a server change like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` because this works from Postman on the same laptop without any special origin handling.

Comment: You are submitting a form and don't listen to form submit events. And without having a form method specified it will use a GET and subsequently submit an ajax request. Which you don't have to `async await` for since you're handling logic in a callback and jQuery doesn't return a async result, but a jqXHR result (https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)
Also think about which algorithms you use when using SSO with javascript only. You don't want to expose your client-secrets to the browser! Your client-id's are fine to expose in the browser.

Comment: You need to use `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the normal form submission when you use AJAX.

Comment: I don't believe I am submitting a form.  That was some of the advise in earlier questions and I made sure that I have a button-type input, not a button.  Also, I get the same behavior if I change the outer `form` elements to `div`.

Because it fails with `div`, I hadn't considered `preventDefault()`.  I can try that but I have little hope.

Comment: The idea of not having to use `async await` is intriguing.  I'll try that.

Comment: Changed `form` to `div` and removed async.  Still failes.

Comment: you're calling `$.post()` if you want a GET request you need `$.get()` or possibly `$.getJSON()`

Comment: I'm calling `$.post()` because I want to post.  The question is why does jQuery turn that into a `GET`?

Comment: probably related to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18934048/1385672 you're trying to post cross domain or are you just testing to see if it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to post data using JSONP on Cross Domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933977/unable-to-post-data-using-jsonp-on-cross-domain)

Comment: Google most certainly does **not** support JSONP (or CORS access for that matter)