# access other site using javascript/html5

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Just wonder is there a way for visitor

when he visits 'a.com' and communicates with the site using XMLHttpRequest, there are some javascript/html5 code hosted on a.com make the visitor can access the content of another site b.com

I memorise that for the security reason this is forbid.

Just make sure if it is possible or not

Comment: search CORS, JSONP and postMessage

Comment: do you mean static html is ok, and url likes http://www.b.com?ref1=abc is ok also, but post to site b.com is forbid?

Comment: your question is too broad for this forum, you need to be more specific http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible using [JSONP](http://json-p.org/) or [CORS](http://enable-cors.org/).

You can read a comparison of the two [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12296910/so-jsonp-or-cors).