# How to make cors request with ajax and jquery only?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am fetching some data from some other third-party website and I am doing this with iff jquery and ajax so, how can I make this happening? because it says origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: use dataType as `jsonp`, available in Jquery's `$.get` method.

Comment: @Ravi — That (a) doesn't use CORS and (b) requires that the server respond with JSONP (which it probably doesn't).

Comment: @Quentin i know it's better to use CORS instead, but i was just providing an alternate. P.S [JSONP or CORS?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12309651/3423104)

Comment: thanks a lot for all u guys for ur suggestions.....

Answer (score 0):

CORS isn't a feature of the *request*. You make the HTTP request with Ajax exactly the same way as you make any other HTTP request with Ajax.

The *server* you are making the request to has to grant permission to the website you are making the request from using CORS headers in the response (and possibly also to the preflight OPTIONS request in the case of a complex request).

You need to add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com` (where the example URL is the origin of the request) to the response headers from the server.

Comment: please check the link below

Comment: @kki3908050 — What about it? That looks like fairly standard code for making a request. As I said, it is the response you have to modify.

Comment: You can't. It would be a pretty stupid security system if the key didn't belong to the person who owned the data.

Comment: ok you are right but somehow now iam able to make cors request by installing cors plugin in chrome browser and it is working fine,now what will you say about this iam getting confused...

Comment: @kki3908050 — Installing a plugin on your own browser will allow you to rewrite the responses from third parties so that it looks like they are setting CORS headers (although it reduces the security of your own data on third party sites). Now you just need to persuade **every single one of your visitors** to switch to Chrome and install the security lowering plugin.

Comment: i really appreciate your synchronous responses for my questions.. thank a lot  Quentin